# Puppeteer works with Dart but not with Flutter (web)

Tags: flutter, dart, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to login to a website in the background of a webapp. When I use my code snippet in a dart script it works fine, but when I do it with Flutter, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._environment
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3       throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/io_patch.dart 279:5                   _environment
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform_impl.dart 83:17                                          get environment
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 177:59                                              get environment
packages/puppeteer/src/puppeteer.dart 299:71                                      defaultArgs
packages/puppeteer/src/puppeteer.dart 135:28                                      launch
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/puppeteer/src/puppeteer.dart 113:25                                      launch
```

This error is triggered when I try to launch the browser:

```
final browser = await puppeteer.launch();
```

Why does it work fine in a dart script but not in Flutter web?